# Compress paddings of class members

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two structs:

```
// sizeof (Bool) == 1
struct Bool {
    bool val;  // 1 bit
               // 7 bits of padding
};

// sizeof (TwoBools) == 2
struct TwoBools {
    Bool b1, b2;  // 16 bits -- 14 of which are paddings!
};
```

As shown in the previous example, although `TwoBools` could've taken up only 1 byte (2 bits of `bool`s and 6 bits of padding), the fact that each member `Bool` has its own padding causes greater space waste. Is it possible in any way to avoid this?

**UPDATE:** As @Olaf pointed out in the comment, my comments in the original code snippets are incorrect. This should be a correct example (on a specific computer, specific OS, with a specific compiler):

```
// sizeof (IntChar) == 8
struct IntChar {
    uint32_t i;  // 4 bytes
    char c;      // 1 byte
                 // 3 bytes of padding
};

// sizeof (TwoIntChars) == 16
struct TwoIntChars {
    struct IntChar a, b;  // 6 bytes of padding
};

// sizeof (CompactTwoIntChars) == 12
struct CompactTwoIntChars {
    uint32_t a, b;  // 8 bytes of ints
    char c, d;      // 2 bytes of chars
                    // 2 bytes of padding
};
```

Comment: Maybe you want bit-fields?

Comment: @SouravGhosh AFAIK bit-fields won't work for opaque types...? If (in C++) I have a class with private members, I can't see how bit-fields can be used.

Comment: Implement a getter/setter...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your comment is wrong anyway. No type can use less than 1 byte.

Comment: Where `bool` is a single bit?

Comment: Getter/setter refers to providing member functions (aka methods) to read (get) and write (set) fields in (private) members.

Comment: Why use a distinct `struct` for a single `bool` anway? Either you want to add more members, then the problem becomes less relevant. Or you don't, then a `bool []` would make more sense (and probably not to use these `struct`s at all).

Comment: @Olaf You're right. I was asking the wrong question; I'll update the question.

Comment: @Olaf In his code, I think the OP is aware that `val` will hold 1 byte, he just means that on 8 bits, only 1 is useful/needed.

Comment: @Olaf _"If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit."_ ??

Comment: @Olaf - as I know you're aware `bool[]` doesn't have the 1-bit/element property the OP is apparently seeking - but `std::bitset` and `std::vector<bool>` do ...

Comment: @ZizhengTai Then you should not have tagged this C, :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Is my updated example not applicable to C?

Comment: @kebs: That is unclear, as, depending on the OS/architecture, `struct` very well can be padded to 8 byte or even larger boundaries for perfomance reasons.

Comment: An obvious counter question would be: Why would you like to avoid padding? I fear it has something to do with serialization. Please write a proper serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @davidbak: I am, but I suspect a typo/confusion between bit and byte. It should be read in context of the other comments, including my preceeding one.

Comment: Re your last edit: C and C++ are different languages. C+ might have other requirements than C. So pick one language and stick to that. Note that the first snippets are not valid C, nor does C support classes. Also note that your edit changed the question completely.

Comment: @Olaf Then I'll stick to C++ ;)

Comment: @Olaf Yes, but I think the original question just wasn't asking what the title suggests at all. I'm aware that what happens to a `bool` isn't padding (it's minimum addressing unit), what I wanted to ask (as the title suggests) is padding a >= 1 byte type to more than its "true" size. I just wasn't thinking clearly when I ask the question in the first place. Sorry!

Comment: You just confirmed my suspection. As I did not answer, I don't mind much. But you should ask whoever posted an answer to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no padding. The smallest addressable memory unit is one (1) byte. If you have two distinct addressable entities then you must use at least two (2) byte. The `sizeof` operator will return the size in bytes not in bits.

For your update: No, it is not avoidable within standard C++ (different memory alignment requirements for certain types on different platforms). It is avoidable for specific platforms with `#pragma pack`.

Comment: There very well is padding.

Comment: For the original or updated example? Because I address only the question and it examples.

Comment: Hmm, I guess `#pragma pack` is the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Before you use such non-standard extension, you should think **why** you want that. If you are up to serialisation/marshalling of data to store/transfer through a serial link: there are better and standard ways using shifts. Or at least use tools like nanopb, etc. which are well augmented against platform-dependencies. Note that you run into other trouble with your way (endianess).

Comment: @Olaf I asked this question entirely because I was curious ;-) Thank you for the reminder though. Seems the pragma is not only non-standard, but also possibly unsafe even where it is recognized by the compiler. On my MacBook even though Clang recognized the pragma and successfully compile the code, the program ran into an immediate segmentation fault upon starting (while gcc does work).

Comment: @ZizhengTai: As I commented below: If this is about serialisation, serach for it. There are better ways with shift&bitops. In general relying on packing is a very bad idea. If you have a memory-restricted system, start not using C++, but C and optimize the code/data manually (e.g. like you did in the second `struct`s). Note that packet `struct`s on many systems can have massive performance penalties (some have to manually pack the bytes to words).

Comment: @ZizhengTai - your seg fault depends on the machine architecture - some architectures (e.g., x86) allow unaligned access (though possibly with a performance hit) and some do not.  It is the programmer's responsibility to deal with it (when choosing non-standard packings).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is allowed to insert *padding* bytes, for alignment, between variables in a structure.

As far as Boolean variables go, there is a rule about the minimal addressable unit, which on many platform is one byte.

Some compilers may have *pragmas* that allow structures to be packed.

If you want to pack Boolean types, you may want to use bits instead.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is mostly about custom (opaque) types. I have updated the question.

Comment: The rule of padding also applies when the data members are custom types (classes or structures or unions).  If you machine likes 16-bit alignment and you have a structure of 3 bytes, the compiler will append 1 byte so that the next variable will align to a 16-bit boundary.

Comment: Some compilers may also have command line switches that control padding - but the pragmas are preferred (though there is no standard gcc does support the Microsoft pragmas).